# How to fix this validation error?

Tags: html, validation, anchor

I have following line in my page:

```
<a href="#" rel="toggle[home_right_animate_div1]" 
   data-openimage="/images/right_btn1_hover.png" 
   data-closedimage="/images/right_btn1.png">
  <img src="/images/right_btn1_hover.png" border="0" alt="" />
</a>
```

When I check this for HTML5 validation I'm getting following errors:

> Error: Bad value toggle[home_right_animate_div3] for attribute rel on element a: The string toggle[home_right_animate_div3] is not a registered keyword.

[image: validation]

Comment: Please add more Informations!

Comment: more info?? `rel="toggle[home_right_animate_div1]" ` this line is giving validation error..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For link elements with an href attribute and a rel attribute, links must be created for the keywords of the rel attribute:

[those keywords over here @ W3](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/links.html#linkTypes)

[image]

In plain english, you need to use one of those keywords, no custom naming convention allowed.

So that gives you 2 options:

- leave it as it is (you probably need it for some scripting), not
  everybody has the browser inspector open to see the error.
- or fix it by adding a custom data-rel attribute maybe, if scripting
  is envolved, you need the re-write that part of the script